# Exercise 1.14 (ii) from Rotman's book "An Introduction to the Theory of Groups".

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations

I'm trying to solve the exercise 1.14 (ii) from Rotman's book  "An Introduction  to the Theory if Groups" that says:

**Let $\alpha$ and $\beta$ be cycles un $S_n$ (we  do not assume that they have the same  length). If there is $i_1$ moved by both $\alpha$ and $\beta$ and if $\alpha^k(i_1)=\beta^k(i_1)$ for all positive integers $k$, then $\alpha=\beta$**

I don't know how to approach the exercise. Can someone help me with some hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's break down the problem.

The section this problem appears in is about cycles, so what does it mean for $\alpha$ and $\beta$ to be cycles? It means we can denote them as $(j_1 \, j_2 \, j_3 \ldots \, j_r)$ and $(l_1 \, l_2 \, l_3 \ldots \, l_s)$.

What does it mean that $i_1$ is moved by $\alpha$ and $\beta$? That just means $\alpha(i_1)\neq i_1$, and $\beta(i_1)\neq i_1$, but in other words $i_1=j_p$ for some $p$ and $i_1=l_q$ for some $q$; that is, the character (if we are thinking of $S_n$ as the group of permutations of $n$ characters) appears in these cycles.

To make things concrete, consider $S_4$ where we let the characters be $\{1,2,3,4\}$. Then the permutation $(123)$ is the one that takes $1$ to $2$, $2$ to $3$ and $3$ to $1$, and fixes $4$. This permutation is a $3$-cycle, where three denotes its length. We can also write the permutation as $(123)(4)$, to emphasize $4$ is fixed, but its not necessary. This permutation moves the characters $1, 2,$ and $3$.

Back to the general case, we have that $\alpha^k(i_1)=\beta^k(i_1)$ for all positive integers $k$. This means that after one application of $\alpha$ or $\beta$, $i_1$ gets sent to the same thing, after two repeated applications of $\alpha$ or $\beta$, $i_1$ gets sent to the same thing, etc.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is that you write some cycle, fix a point $i_1$, and look at what the powers $\alpha^k(i_1)$ do. You should see the pattern very quickly.